# How to filter [IO a]

Tags: haskell

I have a function that reads the content of a file and tries to parse it to `Int`.

```
readIntFromFile :: String -> IO (Maybe Int)
readIntFromFile path = do
    s <- readFile path
    return $ readMaybe s
```

Let's say I called this function several times and ended up with `[IO (Maybe Int)]`. Having this list, I now want to filter `Nothing` values out, so the list contains only successfully parsed `Int` values. To make this happen, I need a function that looks like `fltr :: [IO (Maybe Int)] -> [IO Int]`. And this is where I stuck.

I can use `sequence :: (Traversable t, Monad m) => t (m a) -> m (t a)` to make `IO [Maybe Int]` out of `[IO (Maybe Int)]` and then filter function will be:

```
fltr2 :: IO [Maybe Int] -> IO [Int]
fltr2 k = k >>= onlyJust
    where onlyJust xl = return [y | Just y <- xl]
```

Unfortunately, I don't think `fltr2` can always be used instead of original `fltr`. What if one of the files I read with `readIntFromFile` does not exist?

I'm new to Haskell, and I suspect that I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here. Is there any way to implement filtering through `[IO a]` (in my case `[IO (Maybe Int)]`)? And if it is possible to generalize what should be an approach to filter lists like `(Monad m) => [m a]`?

Answer (score 2):

My first note would be that `[IO (Maybe Int)]` is not a very useful type most of the time, and typically you should prefer to wind up with `IO [Maybe Int]`. Supposing that you have a `[String]` somewhere that you're mapping this function over, you can use `traverse` (or its older synonym, `mapM`) to get the more useful type:

```
map readIntFromFile fileNames :: [IO (Maybe Int)]
traverse readIntFromFile fileNames :: IO [Maybe Int]
```

Having done that, you can use `fmap` to reach through the `IO` and perform operations on its contents. In this case, you want a function of type `[Maybe Int]` -> `[Int]`. If we look on Hoogle for [`[Maybe a] -> [a]`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%5BMaybe+a%5D+-%3E+%5Ba%5D), we immediately find `catMaybes`. So, `fmap catMaybes` has the type you want, and thus

```
fmap catMaybes . traverse readIntFromFile $ fileNames :: IO [Int]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. One more thing I didn't clearly describe in my original question is when to handle IO errors? For example, what if one of the files we are reading with `readIntFromFile` does not exist, and we don't want to halt the whole operation?

The only thing that comes to mind is to change `readIntFromFile` to something like `readIntFromFile2 :: String -> IO (Either SomeException (Maybe Int))` and handle exception inside `fmap`. Does it make any sense? Or is there a better approach?